# What should pool size be, w/ relation to workers, processes, and threads?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, multithreading, heroku, connection-pooling, puma

Is the following correct?

A dyno/worker and process are the same thing.

Puma, the webserver, can fork off multiple dynos/workers/processes for the application.

At the lower level of abstraction, each process has multiple threads (at least in multi-threaded webserver like Puma?). In Rails 5, this is set to 5 threads by default (`/config/puma.rb`) (as an aside, what determines a good threading number?

Each of these threads can handle and respond to one request at a time, and if interacting with the database must have a connection to read and write.

Each thread has a maximum of one connection to the database at any time, and the pool (`/config/database.yml`) is simply a cache of connections to the database (so threads can pickup connections more quickly?).

So, the highest value the pool need ever be is the number of processes (dynos) times the number of threads per process, while remaining less than or equal to the max connections to the database?

Is the pool size setting per dyno/worker/process, or for the whole application? If per process, then the pool should be the same size as the threads on one process, not times all of them?

Thanks!

Comment: Heroku will automatically set the correct pool size with the `DATABASE_URL` env var. https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/rails-database-connection-behavior